# SQL - Copy one column to another

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have a database with a lot of customers and there is a chance that the customer number (`NUMBER(10)`) is about to go out of bounds.

Because of other legacy systems I can't do anything regarding this key. The solution is to add another column that will to be used as a `new` customer reference later.

**Anyhow, is there a way to copy all values from the old column to the new column without downtime?**

If I run this SQL the table is locked (I/O) for about 2-3 minutes (not acceptable)

```
UPDATE table SET new_customer_ref = old_customer_number;
```

---

**EDIT: Thank you guys for all help. I ended up using the solution provided by @Simulant**

This is what I did:

```
-- Copy all old numbers to new reference in batches of 5000
DECLARE
  i NUMBER := 1;
  batchsize NUMBER := 5000;
  maxId NUMBER;

BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(ID) INTO maxId FROM CUSTOMER;

  EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN maxId := 0; /* Prevent endless loop if no  customers. */ 

  LOOP
    UPDATE CUSTOMER SET new_ref = old_number WHERE ID >= i AND ID < i + batchSize;
    i := i + batchSize;
    COMMIT;
    EXIT WHEN i>maxId ;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Only the table will be "locked", definitely **not** the "database". And the table is only locked for other UPDATE or DELETE statements. It's not locked for read of insert statements.

Comment: If `update` is too slow for you, you can always create a new table like:
`Select a,b, old_customer_number, old_customer_number as new_customer_ref from table`. Drop your original table and rename this table to original.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - it seems likely the downtime associated with replacing a table - re-granting privileges, recompiling invalidated code, etc - will vastly exceed 2-3 mins update lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a script (in any language of your choice) that is able to connect to your database and update the values in chunks of 100-1000 rows. In this way you have multiple transactions with a shorter runtime each.

As the migration is now async you should handle in your application code that the new column could be null, while the value was not migrated. In that case rely in the old value and also update the new value when it was changed. If the new value is already present you don't need a special handling. You can remove this fallback handling once the complete migration is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter existing column instead of creating new column.

```
ALTER TABLE Table_name MODIFY customer NUMBER(50);
```

Comment: The OP explicitly stated that they can't do anything regarding this key.

Answer (score 0):

I think in such case `COMPUTED COLUMN` is very helpful if you are allowed to change the structure of the table and in this way you won't need to update records any time

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD [new_customer_ref] AS [old_customer_number]
```